# Como crear sinónimos en postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estuve intentando esto pero me da error no se que parámetros mas se le deba especificar.

```
Create public synonym T_PERSONAS  FOR USR_FACTURACION.FCT_PERSONAS;
```

Comment: ¿Cual error? Siempre se debe incluir los detalles del error en la pregunta. Que yo sepa, no existen los public synonyms en Postgres, tal como lo tiene Oracle. Si te explicas un poco más en cuento a lo que necesitas y por qué, tal vez alguien te puede proponer una alternativa.

Comment: la pregunta seria se puede crear sinonimos en postgres y como seria?

Comment: Que yo sepa, no se puede. Nuevamente, si nos explicas para qué necesitas esto, tal vez alguien pueda sugerirte una alternativa adecuada que se aproxime a lo que buscas.

Comment: la verdad q esta haciendo para oracle pense q si se podia tambien en postgres , muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: En postgres no se necesitan sinónimos, no tiene la misma estructura que Oracle y por tanto no se han desarrollado. Puedes agregar librerías de terceros para ello pero la verdad es que es un tanto inútil.